# 15 second switching circuit

Tags: microcontroller, switches, relay, solid-state-relay

I am designing a circuit that receives a signal from a motion sensor, and then turns on a light for 15 seconds. I have a rough idea on how to make the circuit, but I am also curious what are the different options to implement the circuit.

[image: sample circuit]

1. I think this circuit would do what I am thinking of. Can I or should I use a thyristor instead of a relay?
2. And is there a way to keep the light on for 15 seconds without a microcontroller?
3. I have never used a microcontroller before, so is there any recommendations to what controller to use and what relay/triac to use? (Vdd=7.8V)

Comment: *"should I use a thyristor instead of a relay"* No, unless you add more logic like an optocoupler, a thyristor does not give you galvanic separation from mains. (That is, I assume your light is a mains light. And for DC you can't use a thyristor, it would not stop conducting unless you add even more complex circuits)

Comment: every example I see of a relay or optocoupler deals with high mains voltage. I'm only using a 7.4V battery to power the light. Do I even need galvanic isolation?

Comment: you could use a 555 timer

Comment: @Sandos galvanic isolation is only mandatory when dealing with high volatge like mains, it's not neccessary for 7.4V. What is that light that you want to switch? Eventually you can replace the relay directly with the light

Comment: Can you give some more information about the light? Is it DC or AC powered? What type of light is it?

Comment: As you have never used a microcontroller before I suggest you consider the simpler option of building a monostable timer using a 555 IC. Very cheap and no programming / programmer needed. You can still keep the relay to switch the load.

Answer (score 0):

A thyristor (triac) can be used instead of, mot motion senor lights use this approach. but in these circuits the motion detector circuit is live at mains voltage, so not recommended for beginners.

Often one way to make a 15 second delay is to adjust the delay built into the motion detector,